# How to use groupby,distinct in sql

Tags: sql, asp.net

[This is the table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pF1EN.png)
.

Table name is voyagemaster. How to select distinct Vessel and also one Vessel have lots of voyagenumber, hence I am adding the voyagedate
for select the voyagenumber as max(voyagedate).
According to vessel select max(voyagedate) and voyagenumber.
How to solve..

```
select distinct(Vessel), VoyageID, VoyageNumber, max(VoyageDate) as vdate, VIA,
       ROTNo, CutOffDate, CutOffTime, ETA, ETD
from VoyageMaster
group by Vessel
```

Thank in Advance

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: select distinct(Vessel),VoyageID,VoyageNumber,max(VoyageDate) as vdate,VIA,ROTNo,CutOffDate,CutOffTime,ETA,ETD from VoyageMaster group by Vessel

Comment: Distinct is not a function on a column, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and applies to the whole selected rows. (`select distinct(Vessel), VoyageID...` is the same as `select distinct Vessel, VoyageID...` and also the same as `select distinct Vessel, (VoyageID) ...`...)

Comment: Its not that clear to me. Can you tell something more about your expected result ?

Comment: i am using the autocomplete textbox with Vessel,now when i select the vessel from autocomplete i need to fill other textboxs with latest VoyageNumber and all other feilds

Comment: Suppose  vessel is CAPE MARIN  then voyage number is 1615

Comment: So you want both the rows to be returned or the one with the max vdate. As from your example for CAPE MARIN there are two voyage number 1614 and 1615.

Comment: i want return only one row with voyagenumber 1615

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :

```
SELECT A.Vessel,V1.VoyageID,V1.VoyageNumber,A.VoyageDate 
FROM VoyageMaster V1 
JOIN ( SELECT Vessel,MAX(VoyageDate) VoyageDate  
       FROM VoyageMaster 
       GROUP BY Vessel ) A 
  ON A.Vessel = V1.Vessel 
  AND V1.VoyageDate = A.VoyageDate
```

Comment: showing error:-ambiguous column name 'Vessel' and 'VoyageDate'

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT * from VoyageMaster
where VoyageDate in (select max(VoyageDate)from VoyageMaster group by vessel)
```

Or only the columns you want:

```
SELECT Vessel,VoyageID,VoyageNumber,VoyageDate,VIA,ROTNo,CutOffDate,CutOffTime,ETA,ETD
from VoyageMaster
where VoyageDate in (select max(VoyageDate)from VoyageMaster group by vessel)
```